# Windows Form Doesn't Show C# Timer

Tags: c#, windows, forms, if-statement, timer

Code:

```
while ( int_Timer > 0 )
{
     int int_Ticks = 0;

     if ( int_Ticks < 100)
     {
         int_Ticks++;
     }

     if (int_Ticks == 100)
     {
         int_Timer--;
         lbl_Timer.Text = int_Timer.ToString();
     }
}
```

So I basically tried to make a timer however, since I implemented this code the form doesn't appear in the taskbar. In fact the only indication is the Visual Studio Debug running.

Comment: So, your "timer" is that loop?  That's the wrong way to do it.  There are several "Timer" classes available, one of which is a Windows Forms component - use that instead.  The reason you aren't seeing anything is that your code is going into that loop (likely on the user interface thread) and looping forever.  Windows Forms runs it's own "message processor" on that same thread under the covers.  By looping forever, you are not letting the message processor process messages.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Windows Forms toolbox.  Under "Component", find "Timer".  Drag/drop one onto your form.  It won't show up where you dropped it (it's non-visible), but it will show up in a pane below.

Go to the properties of your new timer (named "timer1" by default) and change:

- Enable to **true**
- Interval to **1000**   *milliseconds, i.e., one second*

Double-click on the `timer1` Timer component on your form designer (at the bottom).  That will create a handler for the default event (`Tick`).

Make that code look like:

```
 private int _count = 0;
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ++_count;
     Tlbl_Timer.Text = _count.ToString();
 }
```

You should see your label start counting at 1 and going up until it overflows (somewhat north of two billion).