# How to update Windows Forms after running them? C# or F#

Tags: winforms, f#

With the code below I am trying to print i in the textbox every second, but it doesn't update the textbox. Am I missing something?

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Threading

let form = new Form()

let textBox = new TextBox()

textBox.Text <- "Hello, World."

form.Controls.Add textBox

Application.Run form

let rec main i =
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    textBox.Text <- sprintf "Hello, World. %i" i
    form.Controls.Add textBox
    main (i + 1)

main 0
```

Comment: Why are you not using a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#?

Comment: Do I have to use a timer? It's tagged C# because you can answer it in C# if you want.

Comment: `Application.Run` is a blocking call (the so called message loop). The code after it will execute basically on application exit (when the main form is closed).

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. So how would I make it work, because I know if I just move it above Application.Run it won't even open because it's infinite.

Comment: Well, use timer (start it inside form `Load` event) as suggested.

Comment: Reiterating what @IvanStoev says: In a Windows Forms app, there's a "message loop" that dispatches events to handlers.  It relies on handlers quickly handling events and returning control back to the forms infrastructure (that loop).  The other thing about Windows Forms is that all of the UI and most/all handlers run on the same thread (aka the _main thread_ or the _UI thread_).  You are calling `Sleep` on that thread, preventing UI update and then updating the form and then sleeping.  If you use a Windows Forms timer (which, works well with WinForms), things should just work

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770432/windows-form-doesnt-show-c-sharp-timer/53770919#53770919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` if you want to periodically update something on the form. Provide the desired interval of timer ticks, add a `Tick` event handler (which updates text in the text box), and start the timer:

```
let form = new Form()
let textBox = new TextBox(Text = "Hello, world.")
form.Controls.Add textBox

let mutable value = 0 // counter
let timer = new Timer(Interval = 1000) // this timer will fire tick events each second
timer.Tick.Add <| fun _ -> // you can ignore argument which is passed to handler
    value <- value + 1
    textBox.Text <- sprintf "Hello, World. %i" value

timer.Start()
Application.Run(form)
```

---

Why your sample does not work? First of all `Application.Run` blocks further execution until you close the opened form. But even if you'll use `form.Show()` to execute recursive function while the form is shown, you would see the form stuck and didn't update. Because you are freezing main thread by `Thread.Sleep` and form is not able to process events and repaint itself. `form.Refresh()` would allow you to see the updates, but between them, the form will be non-responsive. Also, you don't need to add `textBox` to form controls on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just saw this answer. And it has helped me a lot, I can do a lot more now. Thanks!